# Correct type signature for returning an implementation

Tags: c#, types, type-theory

In the following situation:

```cs
/** contract */

abstract class A { }
abstract class B<T> where T : A { }   
abstract class K<M, N> where M:A where N: B<M>{}

/** implementation */

class RA : A { }
class RB : B<RA> { }
class RK : K<RA, RB> { }

/** usage/test */

class Test {
    RK rk = new RK();

    public K<T, TT> GetR<T, TT>() where T : A where TT : B <T> {
        return rk;
    }
}
```

The compiler gives an error on `return rk`:

```
Cannot convert expression type 'RK' to return type 'K<T,TT>'
```

However:

- `RA : A`, so it's valid for `T : A`
- `RB : B<RA>`, so it's `RB : B<T : A>` and it's valid for `TT : B <T : A>`
- finally `RK : K<RA, RB>`, so it's `RK : K<T : A, TT : B<T>>` so it should be valid as well

Questions:

- Where is the error in my logic?
- What signature should `GetR()` have to be able to return as `K<A, B<A>>` anything that implements `K`?

Comment: What if I call your GetR function with `GetR<MyClassFromA, MyClassFromB<MyClassFromA>>` ? Will `RK` implement that?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, it is intended to work this way, but it doesn't for some reason.. just tried abstracting the parameter `K<T, TT>` to something like `Z : K<T, TT>` and making *that* the return type of the function does not help..

Comment: I think I'm missing something fundamental here

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen hmm maybe I am misunderstanding how the type specification should work in this case. Of course `RK` and its type parameters are not going to implement your custom classes. But then I don't know how to write the return type for such a function in C#, so that it would return anything that implements `K` as `K`.

Comment: Why is K abstract? Can't you simple make it non-abstract and construct an instance of it with the two types I passed in?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `K` is abstract because in reality it's `AScriptEngine<ACallArgs, AScriptCall<ACallArgs>>`. The idea is that any script engine has its own type of an object that incapsulates a function call, which, consequently, incapsulates the structure that defines the call args. There are several script engines that should inherit from this class and have their own implementations of these classes, but be treated the same at the higher levels, hence the abstractions.

Comment: If your method is supposed to construct the right thing you will need to know more about each implementation then.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah, well, the engines are constructed somewhere else. They are just intended to be stored in a common storage datastructure and to be accessed via the same API.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is the error in my logic?

You have a method that is generic for any `T` and `TT` (given some constraints) but you return a *specific* implementation. If you call `K` with any types other than `RA` and `RB` the return type would be incompatible.

> What signature should `GetR()` have to be able to return as `K<A, B<A>>` anything that implements `K`?

Your *signature* does that - it's the specific *return value* that's causing the error.  You could do:

```
public K<T, TT> GetR<T, TT>() where T : A where TT : B <T> {
    return rk as K<T, TT>;
}
```

which would return `null` if `T` and `TT` were anything other than `RA` and `RB`.

Comment: So it runs out that the system needs one more rule for these types.. Interesting. Could you please explain a bit more on `If you call K with any types other than RA and RB the return type would be incompatible.`? I was thinking that the `T` and `TT` parameters lock the relationship between the `M` and `N` parameters of `K` so that anything that fits that relationship is correct?